# Let $(X, F)$ be the cofinite topology. Show that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n \not= \{x\}$ for $V_n \in F$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be an uncountable set, and let $F$ be the collection of all subsets $E$ in $X$ which are either empty or co-finite (Which means that $X \setminus E$ is finite). Show that $(X, F)$ is a topology which is not Hausdorff, and is compact and connected. Also show that if $x \in X$, $(V_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is any countable collection of open sets containing $x$, then $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n \not= \{x\}$.

I can do the first part, but I am struggling with the second part. $V_n \in F$ for all $n$. This implies that $\bigcap_{n=1}^N V_n \in F$, and $X \setminus \bigcap_{n=1}^N V_n$ should be finite. Since $X$ is uncountable, this implies that $\bigcap_{n=1}^N V_n$ should be uncountable. This is true for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, but does this mean that $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty V_n$ is uncountable? IF not, how can I approach this question?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* You could try using De-morgan's law instead, and show that $ \underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\cup}}V_n^c \neq X\setminus\{ x \}$.